# Mongo aggregations for different query and same projections along with count

Tags: mongodb, nosql, aggregation-framework

I have three different collections having the following schema.

```
> db.userSettings.find()
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("595fd33167455f32373b5e07"),
    "uid" : 1,
    "tc" : 0,
    "pv" : 1,
    "is" : 1,
    "ns": [],
    "nkey": 1
}

> db.userAgents.find({})

{
    "_id":ObjectId("595fd33167455f32373b5e07"),
    "uid":1,
    "tc":0,
    "pv":1,
    "is":1,
    "ns":[],
    "nid":85
}

> db.notifications.find().limit(1)
{
    "_id":ObjectId("595fe20a67ec8e38a5a9d1b0"),
    "t":5,
    "uid":1,
    "did":1,
    "ir":false,
    "dc":1499456010,
    "h":"Vehicle Fall Detected",
    "msg":"Kind attention! Vehicle number \"JSJEI288282\" experienced a fall at 6:33 am when it wasn't in motion.",
    "c":2,
    "idx":1
}
```

I want to write a mongo-aggregation query for

```
{
   "uid": "for user identifier",
   "dc":  "for last notification in notifications collections for a user sorted by idx",
   "idx": "for last notification in notifications collections for a user sorted by idx",
   "dc":  "for which notification.idx == userSettings.nkey",
   "idx": "for which notification.idx == userSettings.nkey",
   "count": "for notification.idx > userSettings.nkey"
}
```

I am new to mongo and unable to fetch this data using mongo aggregation. I hope(not sure) this is possible in mongo using aggregation in a single query, If not what is the optimal way better than writing the query for all collected data and then filtering on the server side.